# SQL INSERT statement including a WITH and SELECT

Tags: sql, select, insert, with-statement

I am looking to run an INSERT into a table using a WITH CLAUSE before the SELECT. I tried putting the WITH before the INSERT and before the SELECT but I am SQL is not liking the formatting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please include an example of your code, any errors you are getting and expected results.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
INSERT
INTO    values (a,b)  //more values
WITH   table AS
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table1
    )
WITH    table2 AS   //from more tables
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table_2
    )         
SELECT  t.value as a, t2.value as b
FROM    table t 
JOIN table2 t2 on t.value = t2.value //some join
WHERE t.value = 'X'   //other stuff
```